# How to prevent repeated actions from a key being held down?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to make a simple action in a Java FX "game" in which an image of a pig 'jumps' upwards every time the spacebar is pressed. Here is the code for the key event handlers and the Animation Timer that I'm using to actually carry out the action.

Key Handlers:

```
  ArrayList<String> in = new ArrayList<String>();

    s.setOnKeyPressed(
        new EventHandler<KeyEvent>()
           {

            public void handle(KeyEvent e)
            {
                String code = e.getCode().toString();

                 if ( !in.contains(code) ){
                 in.add( code );                          
                 }

            }
        });

      s.setOnKeyReleased(
        new EventHandler<KeyEvent>()
        {
            public void handle(KeyEvent e)
            {                   
                String code = e.getCode().toString();
                in.remove( code );
            }
        });
```

Animation timer:

```
   new AnimationTimer()
{
    double q = 200;
    public void handle(long currentNanoTime)
    {
        double t = (currentNanoTime - startNanoTime) / 4000000.0;    

       if(in.contains("SPACE")){

            q -= 20;

        }

        double y = q + t;

        if(y >= 520){
            gc.drawImage(background1, 0, 0, 1160, 740);
            gc.drawImage(pig, 90, 520, 125, 100);

        }else{
        gc.drawImage(background1, 0, 0, 1160, 740);
        gc.drawImage(pig, 90, y, 125, 100);
        }

    }
}.start();
```

So as you can see I'm having the animation timer simply cause the 'pig' to gradually fall down the y-axis, and when the spacebar is pressed, it is given a slight boost upwards.

The problem is that if the spacebar is held down, the pig just flies continuously upwards without stopping. I want this to be prevented so that the spacebar must be repeatedly tapped and not just held down. So I want only one 'jump' per spacebar press. Nothing that I've tried to workaround it has worked. How can I do this?

Comment: maybe try removing "SPACE" from the `in` list when it is processed in the AnimationTimer's `handle` method (right after `q-=20`) instead of waiting for `onKeyReleased` to be triggered.

Comment: right now what you're doing is that the pig travels upwards until the spacebar is released, which isn't what you want, you just want it to happen once per press, right?

Comment: I have tried that. For some reason, that causes the 'jump' to go up only a tiny bit, and then instantly end, as if removing "SPACE" cancels the animation.

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** *I reworked the answer. The original solution used a counter which prevented the pressed key from having any impact for a certain period of time. Unfortunately, this was not what this question was about. :) The current solution is more straight forward and uses only a simple boolean lock.*

Before answering the question, here are some annoying tips: I would suggest to use `Map<KeyCode, Boolean>` instead of `List<String>` to store information about what keys are currently pressed. It will simplify your code in terms of readability and give it a performance boost at the same time. Next, creating a dedicated object to store information about the pig (haha!) might be a good idea. Finally, using constants instead of hard coded literal values is a good practice.

Also, note that you don't actually need to store information about whether the spacebar is pressed or not and then refer to it from the timer thread. This would only be necessary if you WANTED the pig to be controlled by HOLDING the spacebar. But since you want it to jump only when the spacebar is pressed, you could tell the pig to switch into "jump" state directly from the handler. Of course, this won't solve your problem, because the `onKeyPressed` handler is invoked repeatedly when holding a key for a longer period of time. But I thought it was worth mentioning. :)

Now, to answer the question. If you want to quickfix your current solution and ignore all the "good practice" crap, focus only on the `jumpLock` field of the `Pig` class. The trick is to keep telling the pig to jump repeatedly as you are currently doing, BUT making sure that the pig will obey only when the `jumpLock` allows it to do so.

NOTE: The following solution assumes you will update the state of your game using a fixed interval like every 30 milliseconds. But as noted at the end, this solution can be easily modified to use FPS based timer.

The following class contains constants which you may want to change when tweaking your game in the future:

```
public final class Settings {

    private Settings() {
    }

    public static final double BOOST_VELOCITY = 10.0;
    public static final double GRAVITY = 0.3;
}
```

This class represents the pig. The `x` and `y` fields store information about current position of the pig. `velocityX` and `velocityY` are vectors containing information about the direction and "speed" of the pig in X and Y axis, respectively. `jumpLock` is a simple boolean flag which is actually a solution to your problem. Whenever user makes a jump, this lock is set to `true`. And it will remain so until it will be told to release the lock, which will happen when user releases the spacebar.

```
public final class Pig {

    private double x;
    private double y;
    private double velocityX;
    private double velocityY;
    private boolean jumpLock;

    public Pig() {
        // ...
    }

    public void timeChanged() {
        x += velocityX;
        y += velocityY; 
        velocityY -= Settings.GRAVITY;
    }

    public void jumpBoost() {
        if (!jumpLock) {
            velocityY = Settings.BOOST_VELOCITY;
            jumpLock = true;
        }
    }

    public void releaseLock() {
        jumpLock = false;
    }

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }
```

}

Your handlers could look like this. Notice that `Map<KeyCode, Boolean>` is used to store information about currently pressed keys. It performs better than `List<String>` in this situation. Also adding the `@Override` annotation is a good practice even when overriding methods which are abstract:

```
final Map<KeyCode, Boolean> keyboard = new HashMap<>();
keyboard.put(KeyCode.SPACE, false);

scene.setOnKeyPressed(
    new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE) {  
                keyboard.put(e.getCode(), true);
                // You could alternately call pig.jumpBoost()
                // directly from this handler and not having to 
                // deal with the 'keyboard' map at all
                // as illustrated with by pig.releaseLock()
                // in the next handler
            }
        }
    });

scene.setOnKeyReleased(
    new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent e) {     
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE) {              
                keyboard.put(e.getCode(), false);
                pig.releaseLock(); // IMPORTANT!!!
            }
        }
    });
```

Finally, the following snippet of code must be executed repeatedly. This solution assumes this code will be executed in a fixed interval like every 30 milliseconds. If you are using FPS based timer (meaning there will be irregular interval between executions), you should pass the time which elapsed from the previous update as a parameter to the `timeChanged()` method, and multiply with it whatever necessary inside that method.

```
pig.timeChanged();    
if (keyboard.get(KeyCode.SPACE)) {
    pig.jumpBoost();
}    
// Note that pig.releaseLock() could be called in else 
// branch here and not in the onKeyReleased handler.
// Choose whatever solution suits you best.

// + draw image of the pig on pig.getX() and pig.getY() coordinates
```

Hope I got this right. I was almost asleep when writing this post and misunderstood the question at first. But I really need to earn some reputation points to be allowed to comment on an issue which is currently important to me. Haha! :D:D

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help! This helped me immensely. Good stuff.